# TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I obtain this problem :

```
Response { type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/marks",
redirected: false, 
status: 200, 
ok: true, 
statusText: "OK", 
headers: Headers, 
body: ReadableStream, 
bodyUsed: true }
MarkService.js:5
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: 
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at      
http://localhost:3000/api/marks. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

This is where it points

```
class MarkService {
  constructor() {
    this.URI = `localhost:3000/api/marks`;
  }

  async getMarks() {
    const response = await fetch(this.URI);
    const marks = await response.json();
    return marks;
  }
}
export default MarkService;
```

I'm trying to make a app with express in the backend and Webpack for the frontend.
I have a Rest API in the backend and I can't use it on the frontend.

I'm using Ubuntu with Mozilla Firefox 66.0.2 and Nodejs 11.13.0

When I use the console, it said that the problem is in it

Comment: paste complete error

Comment: What happens on the Network tab in the dev tools?

Comment: Try google’s website instead of the localhost once.

Comment: I haven't got any attempt to connect to localhost:3000/api/marks (where I have the Rest API)

Comment: I have changed the url to www.google.com and I have discovered that its trying to obtein http://localhost:8080/www.google.com

Comment: Can you try to call the REST API in postman or in a browser if it is a GET request?

Comment: Yes, when I try a Get method to the Rest API it works

Comment: Is you front end app running on 8080, if yes then the fetch URL is being considered relative to the localhost.

Comment: I have changed the URL to the complete url 'http://localhost:3000/api/marks' so I don't think that the problem is in the fetch URL

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` in the submit event listener for the client side javascript is what I forgot. Adding that worked for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As i can see for this error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/marks. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)
```

it says that a CORS error has occurred, and that's because the front-end and back-end are hosted under different domain or ports if on localhost, lets explain this a little bet further.

CORS which stands for Cross Origin Resource Sharing is a security policy that applies only to Javascript (Browsers) that blocks websites from accessing other websites using AJAX unless they are explicitly approved using headers.

To solve this, you need to pass certain headers in the response from  the server side that approves CORS for the requesting domain, headers & methods

You can read this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for deep knowledge about CORS
Or you can check this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/cors-in-node) to know how to solve the issue your facing

And there is this [NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) for nodejs to help you with CORS