# React JS: CORS Error causing NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: reactjs, spring, proxy, cors, response

I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55674095/12383456) which already helped me, but after adding the header like this in my proxy.js:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//adding headers to allow CORS
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();

    });
    app.use(proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:8080' }));
}
```

At the fetch() i also added the header to make sure it works:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api',{
            headers:{
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
            },

        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({ contacts: data })
            })
            .catch(console.log)
    }
```

I still get the error: TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

`this.setState({ contacts: data })` should store the JSON Objects that gets delivered by my Backend Java Programm. The JSON Objects are at localhost:8080/api and are just Strings

My React Frontend runs on localhost:3000

[The Response Header looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwIgJ.png)

Where do I need this header in order to not get the CORS error, preferable I would like to work without the npm library "cors", or any browser add-on. I should also replace the '*' with localhost:8080 If I am not mistaken, right?
My finishing goal would be to put these Strings in a PrimeReact Component (A Table) dynamically.

Edit: Full error message requested by sideshowbarker:

Warning:

Cross-origin request blocked: The same source rule prohibits reading the external resource at http://localhost:8080/api. (reason: CORS preflight channel was not successful).

Warning:

Cross-origin request blocked: The same source rule prohibits reading the external resource at http://localhost:8080/api. (Reason: CORS preflight channel failed).

ERROR:

TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

//It's in German so I couldn't upload a screenshot, translated it
I forgot to mention that i put @CrossOrigin on my Restcontroller too

Comment: What’s the exact full error message that the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After countless hours of debugging it turns out that I didnt put an `http.cors();` into my WebSecurityConfig.java
I discovered this after i read this tutorial:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cors-preflight

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment because of low rep, but have you set app.listen(8080); ?

Also I don't think you need to change anything relating to CORS if you are running both at localhost.

Could you perhaps have something change in your browser that could be causing this? Try different browser?

Also I would recommend using axios, defining it to be GET on front and back, making sure when you go to http://localhost:8080/api on browser you get the JSON on your screen.

Comment: I added an app.listen before
```app.use(function(req, res, next) {```
But nothing happened
And localhost shows a JSON